# CPU Cache implementation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, memory, computer-architecture, cache

I have been assigned a project of designing a cache memory with some advanced features (using efficient cache algorithms) and implementing it in VHDL.

I know the required theory for carrying out this project and am trying to implement a 4-way set associative L1 and 8-way set associative L2 cache, but the problem is implementing the code in VHDL and simulating it in Xilinx ISE.

The main problem lies here: even if I implement the cache in VHDL, won't I require an MPU to simulate it? And even if I design an MPU, what exactly would I have to do to simulate the cache (for simulation, as I know, would require to run some sort of program on the system)?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Now, would you say that the actual language - VHDL - is your biggest weakness? If so, you may be better off just going through some tutorials.

Comment: actually, that's not true at all. I already have a hands on experience in VHDL. But, I just haven't worked on a project exploiting VHDL yet. And as you will see, the main problem comes right after the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

To test your cache implementation, you need a simulation testbench. A testbench is additional VHDL code that drives the inputs to your module and optionally monitors its outputs and/or collects statistics on its behavior.

Testbench models are not typically intended to be synthesizable, and can use coding patterns that make the simulation as efficient as possible.

Yes, you could use an actual CPU model and execute real software on that CPU, but it is often more effective to write a simpler "memory access generator" in purely behavioral code whose access patterns you can control. It could be based on pseudorandom numbers, with some parameters that control things like "locality of access", an important factor in cache effectiveness.

Note that you will also need an actual memory (the memory whose contents you are caching) as part of your testbench. Since the point of simulation at this level is to verify the correctness of your implementation, this could be a simple read-only memory model that returns some sort of fixed pattern based on address, which will allow your CPU model to verify that it is getting data from the correct address for each access.

Comment: You can't test a cache with a read-only memory. Writes happen and to make sure every read of address X gets the last value written to address X is critical for cache operation. Caches can use write-through or write-back schemes.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: Yes, I thought about that later. I guess the point is, you really need a memory model that can operate in one of several different modes, depending on which aspect of the cache mechanism you're actually testing.

Comment: but does one really need to keep in mind the cache schemes while simulating cache. if so, what difference can it make?

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need an MPU in your testbench.

Consider how an MPU would interact with your cache : which signals it would drive, what it would drive on those signals, and when.

And write a few procedures which will drive those signals in the same way an MPU would, e.g. to read a byte or write a word to specific addresses in memory. These procedures do not need to be synthesisable so if the MPU would drive a signal 5ns after a clock, the procedure can use the "after" clause to generate the right delay.

This set of procedures is called a "Bus Functional Model" (BFM) of the interface between MPU and cache (you can read a lot about BFMs online).

Then your testbench can be as complex as you want, calling these procedures to read and write memory and verify that the data read is as expected.

Comment: can you be a little more specific as to how can one generate random memory addresses?

Comment: Sure. `math.math_real.rand` or www.osvvm.org